# Error: An account required by the instruction is missing when calling update_primary_sale_happened_via_token method

Tags: metaplex

I'm trying to update primary_sale_happened to true in the metadata's NFT. I have deployed my program with anchor. But when I test it, I have this error printed in the console:  `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing`.
I suppose that I pass wrong inputs to the `update_primary_sale_happened_via_token`, but I didn't get what I have to pass to the method.

Here some context.

This is the code that I'm using in the rust program:

```
invoke(
        &mpl_instruction::update_primary_sale_happened_via_token(
            TOKEN_METADATA_ID,
            ctx.accounts.metadata.key(), // desc="Metadata key (pda of ['metadata', program id, mint id])")
            ctx.accounts.owner_authority.key(), // desc="Owner on the token account")
            ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.key(), // desc="Account containing tokens from the metadata's mint")
        ),
        &[
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.owner_authority.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;
```

Note: `mpl_instruction` is just an alias of `mpl_token_metadata::instruction`

And this is the code from my test file:

```
await program.methods.primarySale(
            new anchor.BN(saleAmount)
        )
            .accounts({
                mint: mint,
                ownerTokenAccount: ownerTokenAddress, // pass to the update_primary_sale_happened_via_token as fourth param
                ownerAuthority: wallet.publicKey, // pass to the update_primary_sale_happened_via_token as third param
                buyerTokenAccount: buyerTokenAddress,
                buyerAuthority: buyer.publicKey,
                metadata: metadataAddress, // pass to the update_primary_sale_happened_via_token as second param
            })
            .signers([buyer])
            .rpc();
```

I get the metadata with this call:

```
const metadataAddress = (await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [
                Buffer.from("metadata"),
                TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
                mint.toBuffer(),
            ],
            TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
        ))[0];
```

The owner_authority is the wallet's publickey which have been used to mint. `wallet.publicKey`

And the owner_token_account is retrieved with this call:

```
const ownerTokenAddress = await anchor.utils.token.associatedAddress({
            mint: mint,
            owner: wallet.publicKey
        });
```

Here are the versions of the libs that I use for the program:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.25.0"
anchor-spl = "0.25.0"
mpl-token-metadata = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
```

What I'm doing wrong with the accounts? Is there an other account to pass to the method?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seams like there needs to be any more accounts needed in this instruction.

Comment: So, if I provide the right inputs to the `update_primary_sale_happened_via_token` method. That should mean, that I have to pass more account(s) to the vec accounts of the `invoke` method?
Something like: `invoke(instruction, $[metadata, owner, token, /* more accounts here? */])`.
N.B. I tried to pass system_program accounts to the vec but does not fix my problem.